# Fake Flash with PhantomJS & Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, flash, phantomjs

found this [snippet for faking flash](https://github.com/mjesun/phantomjs-flash) in PhantomJS. I use PhantomJS (2.1.1) through Selenium to do various automated tests. The problem is that the web app I'm testing needs flash support enabled. Therefore I want to simply fake it, so I can still let PhantomJS run headless.

My question now is how I should implement the snippet in the above mentioned scenario. My guess right now is that I need to implement it somewhere inside GhostDriver. So hopefully one of you has the right answer for me - thanks upfront from my end :)